# Are there circumstances where an unmanaged struct can call the destructor of the managed class containing it?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-cli, overloading, destructor

I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to phrase my error, and also how it could actually come about.

To make a big headache short, I am updating a legacy C++ MFC application to C++/CLI, and this requires converting some unmanaged classes into managed classes. There are some situations where there's a class that contains 12 different unmanaged structs and one managed struct, so I'm attempting to use the Embedded template as described in the following dev blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/branbray/2005/07/20/some-notes-about-mixed-types/

The embedded class I'm using looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
   ref class Embedded {
      T* t;
   public:
      !Embedded() {
         if (t != nullptr) {
            delete t;
            t = nullptr;
         }
      }

      ~Embedded() {
         this->!Embedded();
      }

      Embedded() : t(new T) {}

      static T& operator&(Embedded% e) { return (*e.t); }
      T* operator->() { return t; }
   };
```

The class that's causing me issues is the following:

```
ref struct Instance_t
{
   bool                                   Remote;
   uint32_t                               ID;
   UDPSocketMgr_t                         ^SockMgr;
   Embedded<MsgCounts_t>                  MsgCounts;
   Embedded<Connection_t>                 Connection;
   Embedded<PendingMsgFlags_t>            PendingMsgFlags;
   bool                                   SendPendingMsgs;
   Embedded<PROCESS_INFORMATION>          ProcInfo;

   // these copies of messages will be sent to new instances as the start up
   Embedded<RDI::PlatformAttributesMsg_t> PlatformAttributesMsg;
   Embedded<RDI::PoiFileMsg_t>            PoiFileMsg;
   Embedded<RDI::CommonControlsMsg_t>     CommonControlsMsg;
   Embedded<RTDI::ControlsMsg_t>          ControlsMsg;
   Embedded<RTDI::FlightPlanMsg_t>        FlightPlanMsg;

   Embedded<MessageManager_t> PaMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> PoiFileMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> CommonControlsMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> ControlsMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> SectorMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> PolarPolyMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> GeoPolyMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> GeoPatchMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> FlightPlanMsgMgr;
   Embedded<MessageManager_t> PoiListMsgMgr;
   Embedded<AckedMessages_t> AckedMsgs;
};
```

When I attempt to compile the code, I get the message that:

'AckedMessages_t': class does not have a finalizer called '!Embedded'

For the sake of curiosity, I made a separate data type and put it in the instance_t struct, which caused the error message to shift:

'MessageManager_t': class does not have a finalizer called !Embedded'

The problem is clearly in the Embedded template, but I can't figure out what about it might prompt the compiler to think that unmanaged structs are calling a managed-only destructor of a wrapper class.

Normally, I'd begin commenting out code until I could pin down a particular line that was causing the issue and provide a minimum verifiable example, but the legacy codebase is so interdependent on various systems that doing so would probably take half a week in and of itself.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Has anyone ever seen something like this before? Any help is desperately needed.

Comment: What is `!` in `!Embedded()`?

Comment: In C++/CLI, there are two ways that a method can be destroyed. Either the C++ destructor, or the C# garbage collector. From my understanding, by default, the C# garbage collector will clean up all references to managed objects in structs, but will touch unmanaged objects—ie, C++ pointers. Since each of the C++ and C# garbage collectors have different default behaviors, in C++/CLI managed classes have two destructors: ~Class (for C++ destruction) and !Class (for C# garbage collection destruction).